# REST API Authentication with C# WPF Client

Tags: c#, wpf, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm using API-Platform 3.0 on Symfony 6.1 to build an API-REST. Then I build a REST client with WPF (C#) on .Net 6.0, my problem: I can't authenticate my client to the API. Here is my source code:

```
using ApiClient.DAO.Account;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Windows;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ApiClient.Controller.Account
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour LoginWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class LoginWindow : Window
    {
        public LoginWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void __submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Login login = new Login();
            login.username = "SID-000001";
            login.password = "test";

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login);
            var data = new StringContent(json);

            using var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login", data);

            MessageBox.Show(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

I tried to authenticate on a REST API via a WPF client (C#) but it doesn't work.

Comment: You must ensure that the authentication data like URL, password etc. is correct. A good REST API will return an error message and/or code that helps to identify the issue. Most API usually don't expect plain text authentication info. the protocol usually requires the password to be encrypted following a particular algorithm. It's impossible to help without knowing any details. If this is your REST API then you should be able to debug the authentication procedure. Ensure that the service is actually running and listening to requests. Validate the JSON payload.

Comment: Also note that .NET already provides a library to handle JSON. It is superior in a way as it offers an asynchronous API. [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

Comment: I agree with @BionicCode on this. Furthermore test your api with a tool like Postman to see if the endpoint is responding as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use correct encoding `Encoding.UTF8` for JSON object. And, don't `await` for `PostAsync` and obtain `Result` from `HTTPResponseMessage`.

Here is the improved code:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login);
var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

using var client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.PostAsync($"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login", data).Result;

MessageBox.Show(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```